# form fields under accordian not validating

Tags: jquery, validation

I have couple of accordions and each, have form fields. I am using jquery.validationEngine.js for validation. Default, first accordion is open and only those fields are getting validated. Could someone help me how to validate other form fields and open all accordions to show the required fields?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you post your code here or even a jsfiddle if possible. http://jsfiddle.net

Comment: Please use edits to add information to your question instead of posting multitudes of "answers".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default it won't validate fields within hidden panels, so, just use the `ignore` option to make it work:

```
$("#myForm").validate({
    ignore: []
});
```

Comment: I am getting "Object doesn't support property or method 'validate'" error. Here is the code.

Comment: I have never used jsfiddle.net. I may have to spend some time to learn. Meanwhile I am posting the code I have tha tis validationg but only first accordion fileds. Thanks for the help!

Comment: It looks like you're using some kind of plugin, so you'll need to refer to its help/how to to find an answer.

Comment: I am using github. Isn't it part of Jquery ?Is it a diffrent plugin? https://github.com/jzaefferer/jquery-validation

Comment: GitHub is just a "repository". And the plugin on this link is exactly the one I've posted the answer based on. I don't know why would you get that error message. Check this out: http://jqueryvalidation.org/validate/

Comment: I have js/jquery.validationEngine.js and js/jquery.validationEngine-en.js plugins. Are these accurate?

Comment: I'm not sure where you got this from. I've just downloaded the plugin from that link I've posted here, and the file is named `jquery.validate.min.js`

Comment: I will download this file and try again. When i first downloded, i got it from repository. It was a jQuery-Validation-Engine-master.zip file. It has lots of demose and they used validationEngibe('validate') syntax whic hworked for me.

Comment: I see. This one has lots of demos too. And the website is really helpful.

Comment: If you don't mind, can you please provide me the URL where I can see demo's? I am trying few links on the home page and I am getting "Page  cannot be displayed" I think because the domain has .de which are geting blocked in my company. Thank you!

Comment: If you download the plugin, the demos are on the zipped file. It's easier.

Comment: Hi there, Finally I chnaged to use validation plugin. Some reason it is not even validating. Can you pleas etake a look at jsbin? http://jsbin.com/ihodeh/1/edit

Comment: Man... honestly, I would be surprised if anything is working. The HTML markup is totally invalid. You have multiple DOCTYPEs defined (one in the middle of the page), scripts spread everywhere, unclosed functions, unclosed tags, multiple jQuery libraries added across the page, etc. Please tidy it up and try again.

Comment: I'm in a good mood today, so I've done must of the work for you: http://jsfiddle.net/Ab7xr/